# After 2nd click: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I understand that I cannot access an iframe from javascript, but hear me out.

I have an html page with an iframe. Both the html and the iframe contents are within our company's intranet and the same IP. The only difference is that the HTML is in one port while the iframe contents is in another port.

My html has an iframe that looks like this:

```
<div style="width: 900px; padding-top: 100px;display:none" class="container" id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menuzip">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li onclick="FillDataGrid()" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menuzip">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menuzip" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div id="zipTable" style="width: 900px; height: 800px"> 
        <iframe id="dataframe" src="" width="900px" height="800px" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" ></iframe> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`FillDataGrid()` looks like this:

```
function FillDataGrid()  {
   var doc = document.getElementById('dataframe').contentWindow.document;
   doc.open();
   doc.write('Test');
   doc.close(); 
   var zipSite = "http://12.34.56.78:88/ShowData.aspx";
   var zip = document.getElementById('dataframe');
   zip.src = zipSite;
}
```

When I click "Tab 2" for the first time, the tab shows placeholder with text "Test" and then the `ShowData.aspx` is displayed, which is the expected behavior. In other words, I don't get error `Blocked a frame with origin "/" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`.

It's after I click the tab once again that I get the error.

The URL for the html is http://12.34.56.78:81/Home.html. The IP for the iframe contents (`ShowData.aspx`) is in the same ip, but different port (`http://12.34.56.78:88/ShowData.aspx`).

Are there any workarounds?